# How to Remove Hydrophone Alarm from the First 3 Seconds of Every Recording

Tags: soundscape, hydrophone, data-processing

I am currently doing soundscape analysis across three years. However, the data from one of the years has a hydrophone alarm while the other two years do not. As you can understand, this is a problem when I am trying to compare noise values.

Does anyone have recommendations on how I can remove the first 3 seconds from each file (about 1100 files)? I know Audacity has some trimming functions, but I am hoping for a way to do it in a batch (R, Sox-o-matic, or another program?). I would then also need to add 3 seconds to the name of the file (to reflect the new start time).

Thanks in advance!

Melanie Smith
UNH MS Student

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there was a
[similar question on this SE](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-automatically-ignore-sections-of-sound-files-crop-wav-files-before-proc)

at least one of the answers gave a sample script (in R) to remove the initial couple of seconds

Comment: Thank you so much!